# Is it possible to transmit error frames on to bus with CANalyzer?

Tags: testing, prototype, hardware, can-bus, canalyzer

I am looking to transmit error frames onto my CAN bus at a periodic rate for testing purposes. I have CANalyzer and cannot see this as an option anywhere.

I am currently just running a wire from GND to the CAN wires to force errors on the bus but this isn't ideal.

Appreciate any help!

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it would be sufficient to hook up a 2nd instance of the software and have it send frames with the wrong baudrate at even periods? Like if you go for 10bps, each such frame will dead certain give stuffing errors in case you are running on the more common baudrates >125kbps.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call

```
output(errorFrame)
```

to send an errorframe.

If you do not want to send the errorframe on the first bus, you can add the bus name as well:

```
output(CAN2.errorFrame)
```

Comment: Where would I enter this call?

Comment: @Matt In the CAPL of a node connected to the bus, where you want to issue the error frame